# Returning a copied object

Tags: c++, temporary, copy-elision

In a function like:

```
template<class Iterator>
A simple_return(Iterator it)
{
    return *it;
}

A a = simple_return(my_it);
```

The compiler can easily perform a RVO, so do that:

```
template<class Iterator>
A simple_return(Iterator it)
{
    A tmp = *it;
    return tmp;
}
```

However, I have seen the second way is sometimes preferable over the former, for example in STL algorithm implementations (gcc), and I want to know if that affects RVO in any way (as `std::move(*it)` or `std::move(tmp)` does), or has any other reason, for example, regarding conversions or anything else.

For example, `reserver_iterator`, instead of:

```
reference operator*() const
{
     return *--Iterator(current);
}
```

uses:

```
reference operator*() const
{
     Iterator tmp = current;
     return *--tmp;
}
```

I ask that because, for implementing overloadings like `operator+`, I use extensively the pattern:

```
friend A operator+(const A& a, const A& b)
{ return A(a) += b; }
```

instead of:

```
friend A operator+(const A& a, const A& b)
{
    A tmp(a);
    return tmp += b;
}
```

Which isn't specially more readable but makes it be 3 lines longer (this two sentences in one line would be ugly).

Comment: `*--Iterator(current)` does not work if `Iterator` is a pointer type.

Comment: @cpplearner Ok, so simple. Write it as an answer if you want. I will accept it as the valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

Due to named return value optimisation (NRVO), both variants of `simple_return` should produce the exact same machine code. [And they do, even with conversions](https://godbolt.org/g/GVvd8O). As a result, there shouldn't be any practical difference between the two.

As mentioned by @cpplearner, it is done in your STL example because prefix decrement cannot be used on rvalues (e.g. if Iterator is a pointer). This may be the case in other parts.

Comment: The reason has already been pointed out in a comment on the question.

Comment: @hvd, changed the answer to mention that.

Comment: The comment was correct, but I don't think your answer is. For plenty of rvalues, the prefix decrement operator can be used. For pointers it can't, but when you're dealing with iterators implemented as classes, `Iterator(current)` is still an rvalue. It's just that on *that* rvalue, prefix decrement may be supported as well.

Comment: Primitive types hasn't `this` pointers. So, modifiers operators requires lvalues, to modify the object and not the value. However, temporaries of class types, although there are rvalues, have `this` pointers, and you can called any function member through rvalues of class type. I don't know how all of it is translated in Standard terms, but the reason `operator--()` works with rvalues except pointers must be related with this.